# how to configure webstorm to warn about debugger and log statements in files before commit

Tags: webstorm

Is there any way I can configure `Webstorm` to warn me before commit if log staments

```
console.log();
```

or debugger

```
debugger
```

is found in source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do this currently - please vote for [WEB-8324](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8324) and [WEB-8325](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8325)

You can try using external tools like uglify.js to remove these statements from your code - see http://jstarrdewar.com/blog/2013/02/28/use-uglify-to-automatically-strip-debug-messages-from-your-javascript/, for example